# Concatenar dos fechas y darles formato en Mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente problema, necesito concatenar dos fechas y darles formato, los dos campos de fechas que quiero concatenar, solo quiero mostrar una fecha, ya que la otra regularmente va vacio. Algunas productos no tienen fecha, entonces se le coloca "N/A". La consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
A.codigo_producto, B.nombreproducto, date_format(A.fechakardex, '%d/%m/%Y') as fechak,
CONCAT_ws('',A.requientrada,'',A.requisalida) As referencia,
CONCAT_WS('',G.nombreservicio,'',J.nombre) As remitente,
ifnull(A.cantentrada, '0.00') as cantidade, ifnull(A.precio_entrada, '0.00') as precioE,
ifnull(TRUNCATE((A.cantentrada * A.precio_entrada),2), '0.00') AS totalentrada,
CONCAT_WS(A.fechavenci,'',A.fecha_salida) as fechav,
CONCAT_WS('',A.nolote,'',A.lote_salida)as Lote,ifnull(A.cantsalida, '0.00') as cantidads,
ifnull(A.saldo_stock, '0.00') as saldostock,
CONCAT_WS('',ifnull(A.precio_entrada, '0.00'),'',ifnull(A.precio_salida,'0.00')) as precioU,
CONCAT_WS('',F.Obersvaciones,'',h.Obersvaciones) as observaciones
FROM tbl_kardex A
LEFT JOIN tbl_productos B ON A.codigo_producto=B.codigobarras
LEFT JOIN tbl_salidas F ON A.requisalida=F.requisalida
LEFT JOIN tbl_servicios G ON F.tbl_servicios_codigoservicio= G.codigoservicio
LEFT JOIN tbl_entradas H ON A.requientrada = H.requientrada
LEFT JOIN tbl_proveedores J ON H.tbl_proveedores_codigo_proveedor=J.codigo_proveedor
WHERE A.codigo_producto='19072017A005266006'
and A.fechakardex>='2017-10-17' and A.fechakardex<='2018-10-23'
```

La cuestion aqui es que me devuelve fechav, de la siguiente forma:

> 2022-12-310000-00-00

yo quisiera que me devuelva de la siguiente forma:

> 31-12-2022

y quiero que omita la fecha

> 00-00-0000

de antemano gracias, no se mucho de mysql...

Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Para lo que quieres hacer, puedes usar estas funciones

Para dar el formato que quieres a la fecha sería de esta manera

> DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%j-%m-%Y');

Para poder comprobar si la fecha es nula o esta vacía podrías usar esta

> IF(col IS NULL OR col = '', 'empty', col)

Haciendo una mezcla de las dos, podrías tener algo similar a esto

```
IF(fecha1 IS NULL OR col = '', DATE_FORMAT(fecha2,'%j-%m-%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(fecha1,'%j-%m-%Y'))
```

donde la idea es mirar si `fecha1`, es vacía o nula, que es el caso que quieres que no aparezca. En caso de estar vacía, se formateará la segunda fecha, que debería existir en tu sistema, en caso contrario se formatearía la `fecha1`

Comment: #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'FROM tbl_kardex A
LEFT JOIN tbl_productos B ON A.codigo_producto=B.codigobarras' en la linea 12

Answer (score 0):

al ejecutar mi consulta me sale lo siguiente:

> #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'FROM tbl_kardex A
>   LEFT JOIN tbl_productos B ON A.codigo_producto=B.codigobarras' en la linea 12

la consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
A.codigo_producto, B.nombreproducto, date_format(A.fechakardex, '%d/%m/%Y') as fechak,
CONCAT_ws('',A.requientrada,'',A.requisalida) As referencia,
CONCAT_WS('',G.nombreservicio,'',J.nombre) As remitente,
ifnull(A.cantentrada, '0.00') as cantidade, ifnull(A.precio_entrada, '0.00') as precioE,
ifnull(TRUNCATE((A.cantentrada * A.precio_entrada),2), '0.00') AS totalentrada,
IF(a.fechavenci IS NULL OR a.fechavenci = '', DATE_FORMAT(a.fecha_salida,'%d/%m/%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(a.fechavenci,'%d/%m/%Y')) as fvenci,
CONCAT_WS('',A.nolote,'',A.lote_salida)as Lote,ifnull(A.cantsalida, '0.00') as cantidads,
ifnull(A.saldo_stock, '0.00') as saldostock,
CONCAT_WS('',ifnull(A.precio_entrada, '0.00'),'',ifnull(A.precio_salida,'0.00') as precioU,
CONCAT_WS('',f.Obersvaciones,'',h.Obersvaciones) as observaciones
FROM tbl_kardex A
LEFT JOIN tbl_productos B ON A.codigo_producto=B.codigobarras
LEFT JOIN tbl_salidas F ON A.requisalida=F.requisalida
LEFT JOIN tbl_servicios G ON F.tbl_servicios_codigoservicio= G.codigoservicio
LEFT JOIN tbl_entradas H ON A.requientrada = H.requientrada
LEFT JOIN tbl_proveedores J ON H.tbl_proveedores_codigo_proveedor=J.codigo_proveedor
WHERE A.codigo_producto='19072017A005266006'
and A.fechakardex>='2018-01-09' and A.fechakardex<='2018-01-09'
```

Comment: Esto parece un error distinto al que habias puesto al principio. Deberias abrir una nueva pregunta.